# Gin web application only rendering one template

Tags: go, go-gin, go-html-template

I have a Gin web application with multiple HTML templates based off a set of partials and a base template. The base template seems to render fine along with the relevant partials, but my main views, login, index and register do not render as expected. Whenever I visit the HTTP endpoints for any of these, only the register view renders.

What is missing or misconfigured in the below files which is preventing my routes rendering the requested page?

My project has the following structure.

```
├── app
...
│   ├── handlers
│   │   ├── general
│   │   │   └── general.go
│   │   └── routes.go
│   ├── main.go
│   ├── reloadDev.sh
│   ├── static
│   │   ├── css
│   │   ├── img
│   │   └── js
│   └── templates
│       ├── home
│       │   ├── index.tmpl.html
│       │   ├── login.tmpl.html
│       │   └── register.tmpl.html
│       ├── layouts
│       │   └── base.tmpl.html
│       └── partials
│           ├── footer.tmpl.html
│           ├── head.tmpl.html
│           └── navbar.tmpl.html
```

base.tmpl.html

```
{{ define "base" }}
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="eng" data-bs-theme="dark">
    {{ template "head" . }}
    {{template "navbar" .}}
    <body>
    {{ block "content" . }}{{ end }}
    </body>
    {{template "footer" .}}
</html>
{{end}}
```

register.tmpl.html

```
{{ template "base" . }}
{{ define "content" }}
<div class="container">
    <div class="row">
        <div class="col-md-6 offset-md-3">
            <h1>Register</h1>
            <form action="/register" method="post">
                <div class="mb-3">
                    <label for="username" class="form-label">Username</label>
                    <input type="text" name="username" id="username" class="form-control" placeholder="Username" required>
                </div>
                <div class="mb-3">
                    <label for="password" class="form-label">Password</label>
                    <input type="password" name="password" id="password" class="form-control" placeholder="Password" required>
                </div>
...SNIP...
                <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary">Register</button>
            </form>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
{{ end }}
```

index.tmpl.html (Login has the same structure as these two.)

```
{{ template "base" . }}
{{ define "title" }}Home{{ end }}
{{ define "content" }}
<div class="container">
    <div class="row">
        <div class="col-md-6 offset-md-3">
            <p>Welcome to Astra Porta.</p>
            <p>Click <a href="/login">here</a> to login.</p>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
{{ end }}
```

The HTML templates are bundled with the binary using `embed.FS`.

```
//go:embed templates/partials/* templates/layouts/* templates/home/*
var files embed.FS

func main() {
    router := setupRouter()
    err := router.Run()
    if err != nil {
        panic(err)
    }
}

func setupRouter() *gin.Engine {
    router := gin.Default()
    subFS, e := fs.Sub(files, "templates")
    if e != nil {
        panic(e)
    }

tmpl := template.Must(template.ParseFS(
    subFS,
    "layouts/*.html",
    "partials/*.html",
    "home/*.html",
))
router.SetHTMLTemplate(tmpl)

router.StaticFS("/static", http.Dir("static"))

err := router.SetTrustedProxies(nil)
if err != nil {
    panic(err)
}
handlers.InitializeRoutes(&router.RouterGroup)
return router
}
```

And the pages are rendered within my application routes. The references here map to the file names of the `*.tmpl.html` files.

```
func SiteIndex(c *gin.Context) {
    c.HTML(http.StatusOK, "index.tmpl.html", nil)
}

func GetRegister(c *gin.Context) {
    c.HTML(http.StatusOK, "register.tmpl.html", nil)
}

func GetLogin(c *gin.Context) {
    c.HTML(http.StatusOK, "login.tmpl.html", nil)
}
```

Comment: Template names must be unique, i.e. you can't have multiple templates with the same name (e.g., `content`) in a single `tmpl` object. Therefore, for a "base" template to be useful you'd need to parse each `home` template separately and execute the resulting `tmpl` objects individually, rather than parsing all files as a single object. And if you must have a single object, then you need to stop using the "base" template pattern, and instead "compose" your `home` templates out of the partials.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For anybody else having this issue. The solution noted in mkopriva's comment was correct. I removed `base.tmpl.html` and composed each view using updated partials and the target page.

header

```
{{ define "header" }}
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="eng" data-bs-theme="dark">
{{template "navbar" .}}
    <body>
    {{ block "content" . }}{{ end }}
        <head><meta charset="UTF-8">
            <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
           ...SNIP...
            <title>App</title>
        </head>
{{end}}
```

footer

```
{{define "footer"}}

        <div class="container">
            <footer class="py-3 my-4" data-bs-theme="dark">
                <ul class="nav justify-content-center border-bottom pb-3 mb-3">
                    <li class="nav-item"><a href="/" class="nav-link px-2 text-body-secondary">Home</a></li>
                </ul>
                <p class="text-center text-body-secondary">© 2024 .</p>
            </footer>
        </div>
    </body>
</html>
{{end}}
```

Page in question

```
{{template "header"}}
<div class="container">
    <div class="row">
        <div class="col-md-6 offset-md-3">
            <p>Welcome to Astra Porta.</p>
            <p>Click <a href="/login">here</a> to login.</p>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
{{template "footer"}}
```